# Latex: \usepackage{setspace}

Tags: latex

I'm new to Latex. I've beean able to install it and to compile some pdf files. My problem appears when using the following source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
Hello, world! 
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this code it does not work. In the logs I can see what I think is the process of reading the different packages used (i.e. C:\Program Files\MiKTeX2.8\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty).

If I place "\usepackage{setspace}" right after "\documentclass[11pt]{book}" it looks like it's not doing anything. Can the problem be that I don't have this package? I've looking gor info about it, but it'not clear to me which package I need and how to install it.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using TeXnicCenter, there is a bug between that and miktex 2.8 that if you have miktex set to autoinstall packages, it will fail. you need to either set that option to "Yes" or "No" in the miktex config program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you don't have the package. Grab it off the CTAN:

https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace

The quick hack is to just drop the .sty file in the same directory as your .tex document - if you want to install it properly, check your LaTeX documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that MiKTeX has a tool to search and install packages.

Start --> MiKTeX 2.8 --> Maintenance --> Package Manager